# Как правильно дать ссылку в комментариях?

Tags: поддержка, комментарии, markdown, ссылки

Уважаемые коллеги! 
Что-то не получается дать ссылку в комментариях да так, чтобы она подсветилась синеньким цветом! Вот [тред](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585809/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-opengl),  взгляните пожалуйста на второй комментарий снизу. Что-то у меня не отрисовывается ссылка, хотя я справку смотрел (честно-честно).

**Вопрос:** Как правильно дать ссылку в комментариях? 
[image: скриншот непоняток]

Comment: одного слэша не хватает после `http:/`

Comment: `[ответ](http:/goo.gl/2K8CMA)` < `http://`!

Comment: А тут даже нет причины закрытия *"вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится или опечаткой"*. Мигрируем на основной сайт как вопрос по Markdown? :D

Comment: @D-side, кастомные-то есть.

Comment: Ок. Тогда "Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что проблема вызвана банальной опечаткой." Вот.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, @D-Side, где ответы-то???`

Comment: @D-side перенести на основной, там закрыть с упомянутой причиной, а потом обратно на Мету. Где он и будет удалён через некоторое время :)

Comment: щас попробую  [этот пост](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4014/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0-ru-stackoverflow-com?noredirect=1#comment13058_4014)

Comment: @AndrewKachalin сначала квадратные скобки, потом круглые!

Comment: @alexolut всё разобрался. Я просто на обед ходил. Чо удалять по правилам? Или закрываем?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin к чёрту правила!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да Вы бунтарь! Так можно и 416 схлопотать :)

Comment: @alexolut 416 Range Not Satisfiable =)

Comment: @NickVolynkin ещё как Satisfiable. Доказано. <s>Занусси.</s> NicolasChabanovsky :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема была в слеше, поправил ваш комментарий:

> Помните ваш [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/582140) по массиву пикселей?

```
 Помните ваш [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/582140) по массиву пикселей?
```

Пожалуйста, не используйте сервисы для сокращения ссылок. Такие ссылки всегда вызывают подозрение. Как видите, на SO и так можно делать достаточно компактные ссылки.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ссылке последнее число это id пользователя, который нажал "поделиться", добавляется ради счётчиков, его можно убирать.

Вместо нажимания ссылки мышкой можно [включить управление с клавиатуры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) и нажимать <kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: вдвойне спасибо. А то ctrl+c : +v из браузера действительно очень длинно.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin длинно, но быстрее. При желании, "хвост" можно удалить.